# Separation of code and reducing repetition

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm currently working on a web application and over time I've built up numerous pages that are pretty much exactly the same, the only differences are the data shown and the odd control and/or attribute.

So I have 3 pages: A, B & C.

A has a gridview and 4 checkbox filters, B also has this but C has 10 filters and a different row attribute. Is there a way I can merge all the code into one but at the same time allowing each page to be customized without affecting the others.

I tried using master pages but this didn't seem to work as well as I initially planned.

Any suggestions?

***Happy to provide additional information!***

***edit:***
By 'customize', I mean In a few months time I can append a textbox and apply some logic that won't affect the other pages.

Comment: User controls. Wrap your gridview and filters into a single control, and with properties setup you can make it as adjustable as you'd like

Comment: What if the gridview has an onrowdatabound event where half of the code contained is unique to one page and the other half is wanting to be shared between all gridviews onrowdatabound events?

Comment: Easy - just proxy that event outside. Catch event inside the user control, do common work and raise an event for outsiders to handle. Outsiders being your pages, each of which handles it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a user control.  If the onrowdatabound event is page specific just have that event call a function where you have page specific code.  The pages that have the same event functionality can all call the same function while the unique one calls it's own.